# La imagen de mi objeto no se ve en Wollok Game

Tags: poo

Estoy armando un ejemplo muy sencillo de Wollok Game, basándome en la [documentación](http://www.wollok.org/documentacion/conceptos/):

Este es mi **game.wpgm**

```
import pepita.*
import wollok.game.*

program PepitaGame {

//  CONFIG  
    game.title("Pepita")
    game.height(10)
    game.width(10)

//  VISUALES
    game.addVisual(pepita)

//  START
    game.start()
}
```

Y aquí **pepita.wlk**

```
object pepita inherits PersonajeAnimado {
    var posicion = game.at(3,3)
    method imagen() = "pepita.png"

}
```

Ejecuto el programa, veo el tablero correctamente, pero mi objeto no está.

Mi estructura de archivos es:

```
proyecto
|_src
     |__game.wpgm
     |__pepita.wlk
|_assets
       |__pepita.png
```

Si cambio el nombre del archivo por otro (que no existe), me aparece el objeto con el logo de Wollok.

Creo que reconoce el archivo, porque no me muestra el logo de Wollok, pero no entiendo por qué no lo muestra.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo resolví. Descubrí que en realidad estaba mostrando la imagen de mi objeto. Al ser esta muy grande y con fondo transparente, no se veía más que la parte del fondo transparente.

Así es cómo se maneja Wollok con las imágenes del Wollok Game:

- Cada espacio del tablero mide 50x50 px.
- La imagen elegida en `method imagen()` se muestra con el tamaño real, sin cambios.
- Si la imagen es demasiado grande, excederá el espacio del tablero al que fue asignada.

En mi caso particular, la imagen era un PNG de fondo transparente, de 1000x1000, y mi tablero medía 500x500 (10 cuadrados de 50px en cada eje), por lo que sucedió que no se mostraba la parte visible en el tablero real.